# Compute the outer product of two matrixes with a sparse matrix mask

Tags: algorithm

Given: two column vectors `a`, `b`. Let the matrix from their outer product be `P`:

```
P = a * b^T
```

where `^T` denotes the transpose.

Also given: a sparse matrix `S` whose entries are only 1s and 0s.

I want to compute the following matrix:

```
S % P = S % ( a * b^T )
```

where `%` denotes element-wise multiplication of the two matrices.

In other words, I want the matrix whose elements `(i,j)` are:

- The product of elements `a_i * b_j` for `S_ij = 1`, or
- Zero for `S_ij = 0`.

The formula `S % (a * b^T)` involves computing many products that are set to zero anyways, so this does not seem very efficient. Another way to do it is to loop through the elements of the sparse matrix `S` and manually compute the product `a_i * b_j`, but I wondered if there is a faster matrix/vector computation to do this.

Thanks

Comment: The sparse matrix is stored in a sparse way? The way matrices are represented (stored in memory) really makes a difference in designing a good algorithm.

Comment: Yes - specifically I am using the armadillo library in C++, and there is a `sp_mat` class